# reCaptcha values not appearing in $_POST

Tags: php, forms, dom, handler, recaptcha

I am trying to use reCaptcha on my site, and recaptcha_challenge_field, and recaptcha_response_field are not being added to the $_POST array on the backend - but the rest of the variables from my form are.

Any ideas? I have double checked the public/private keys.

Here is the generated HTML:

```
 <form action='myform.php' name='myform' id='myform' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <tr class='select'>
      <td class='label'>Name:</td>

      <td>
        <input type='text'  name='name'  id='name'  class='inputtext'  maxlength='25'  size='25' >
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='select'>
      <td class='label'>Email:</td>
      <td>
        <input type='text'  name='email'  id='email'  class='inputtext'  maxlength='25'  size='25' >

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='select'>
      <td class='label'>Message:</td>
      <td>
        <textarea class='inputtext' name='message'  rows='10' cols='45'></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class='select'>
      <td class='label'>Are you human?</td>
      <td>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=MY_KEY"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=MY_KEY" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td style='text-align: left;' colspan='2'>
        <input type='submit' class='button' value='Send message'>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
```

Here is my handler so far:

```
print_r($_POST);


require_once('inc/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

print_r($resp);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
       "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: I'm having the exact opposite problem :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conceivably you might be having DOM problems because of the way you're interleaving `<table>` and `<form>`.  Try moving your `<form>` and `</form>` tags outside your `<table>` and `</table>` respectively.

Comment: This was a great help, but does anyone know why? I'm assuming the recaptcha javascript walks the DOM and chokes then removed the fields, since "normal" HTML form elements are submitted ok. It would be super-helpful if it either indicated this in HTML or at least logged to the Javascript console, if this is what's going on.